# Application crashed from the main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My iPad application crashed with the following crashlog

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3290732c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c7c208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c75316 __abort + 86
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c752ba abort + 122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c87efa szone_error + 262
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c88b2a free_tiny_botch + 78
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34c33934 szone_free + 404
7   CoreFoundation                  0x374ab730 CFAllocatorDeallocate + 116
8   CoreFoundation                  0x374ab6a4 CFRelease + 1052
9   UIKit                           0x30704d98 -[UILabel dealloc] + 132
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d316e _objc_rootRelease + 30
11  UIKit                           0x30697d34 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 176
12  UIKit                           0x306c009e -[UIView dealloc] + 266
13  UIKit                           0x30704d08 -[UIControl dealloc] + 88
14  UIKit                           0x307c8a26 -[UITextField dealloc] + 566
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d316e _objc_rootRelease + 30
16  UIKit                           0x30697d34 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 176
17  UIKit                           0x306c009e -[UIView dealloc] + 266
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d316e _objc_rootRelease + 30
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d4e50 objc_release + 32
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d3ea6 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 218
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d3dc2 _objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 6
22  CoreFoundation                  0x374b2cf8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
23  QuartzCore                      0x35e0d4b8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
24  CoreFoundation                  0x37536b14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
25  CoreFoundation                  0x37534d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
26  CoreFoundation                  0x375350aa __CFRunLoopRun + 754
27  CoreFoundation                  0x374b849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
28  CoreFoundation                  0x374b8366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
29  GraphicsServices                0x376b1432 GSEventRunModal + 130
30  UIKit                           0x306c4cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
31  TestAPP                         0x000023aa main (main.m:15)
32  TestAPP                         0x00002368 start + 32`enter code here`
```

After looking in to this crash log I could not take any clue on the crash log.
Can some one help me to solve this.

Comment: Looks memory-related, but without seeing your code I doubt anyone would know for sure.

Comment: Can I get any clue.. I mean specific area to look

Comment: Are you using ARC? What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: Also, does it crash all the time? Or after some time, or some event?

Comment: @Resh32 No I am not using ARC. and its not crash all the time.

Comment: @ganuke, like I said in a comment below, it seems like your objects are being auto-released by an autorelease pool. Every place where you use autorelease is a potential suspect ;-)

Comment: @ganuke I suspect that it is a view or view controller that is getting autoreleased. How many viewcontroller do you have?

Comment: Also, please show you you show these viewcontrollers on the screen please.

Comment: this quetion is very similar to _"my cars fallen in to the ravine and the engine is not started. what is the problem?"_

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that this is the telling line '-[UITextField dealloc]' - so the textfield is dealloced, and its cleaning up all its objects. The most likely object that would crash this is the "text" attribute, but it could be any other attribute you have set that was retained by that textField.

So the first thing to do is track down which textField is causing the crash, then looking at everything you have set on that object.

For example, (non ARC):

```
NSString *text = textField.text; // you don't own this object
[text release];
```

could possible cause the crash (didn't test this). The textField has lots of properties - views that can be set - and if you set one and over released it could cause the crash.

EDIT: Look at these lines:

```
17  UIKit                           0x306c009e -[UIView dealloc] + 266
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d316e _objc_rootRelease + 30
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d4e50 objc_release + 32
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x315d3ea6 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 218
```

Going bottom to top, he system would appear to be popping the autorelease pool, which then first calls the UIView dealloc, then starts freeing objects owned by that view. That's my interpretation but I am not an Apple engineer so I don't know 100% for sure.

Comment: -1 I do not agree with you. The root cause is down the stack where a auto-release pool is released (_CFAutoreleasePoolPop). This causes some view to get released and then some textfields in the view

Comment: Exactly what I said - the textField is getting released, and IT is releasing everything it owns, and one of the things it thinks it owns is already released - the crash is inside "CFAllocatorDeallocate". It actually looks like the textField's label release caused it, and so one of its properties is probably the culprit.

Comment: Do you agree that the root cause of the stack error is at the bottom of the stack trace?